# How can I assign partial JSON to script variables

Tags: bash

So I have a JSON file which I grep for certain variables:

```
cat myfile | grep -E "group_(var1|var2|var3)"
```

The output comes out like this:

```
"group_var1": "value1"
"group_var2": "value2"
"group_var3": "value3"
```

I'd like to interpret this in my bash script such that I would end up with the three variables themselves so that I could manipulate them further.

e.g.

```
echo "$group_var1  $group_var2   $group_var3"
```

So far I've tried with `read -a`, `awk '{ print $1 $2 }'`, but none of that brought me closer to my desired result.

The furthest I got was removing the quotes with the following code, but after that, I'm stuck:

```
params=`cat myfile | grep -E "group_(var1|var2|var3)"`
params=${params//\"}
```

echoing params now nets me this:

```
group_var1:value1,group_var2:value2,group_var3:value3,
```

But now I'm stuck...

Edit & solution:

I went digging further and I got it working by crudely invoking awk for each variable I wanted.

```
group_var1=`awk '$1=="group_var1:" { sub(",", "", $2); print $2 }' <<< $params
```

Comment: Once you have the result like in the last row, you can try awk to separate those.

Comment: Also you should consider jq for this task, if you have access to it: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: @g_bor: I could use awk - had a bit of success with it - but do you mean I should then use one call with awk to assign one variable in the script? How would I go about doing that?